# Why does YouTube return different results in browser than from raw HTTP request?

Tags: web-scraping, youtube, jsoup

I'm writing a method that searches YouTube using a HTTP request to the www.youtube.com/results page. However, I noticed a difference when I compare the results I'm getting to the results from inspect element when I perform the same search in Chrome. What causes this?

I set the user agent string to Mozilla/5.0 in the request, so I was expecting the results from my browser to match the results of the method. Instead, I see that the method response contains tags with the class "yt-lockup-title", but using inspect element no such class is there.

```
public static String search(String query) throws IOException {
    Document results = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/results").data("search_query", query).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
    System.out.println(results.body());
    return results;
}
```

The method prints HTML containing `<div class="yt-lockup yt-lockup-tile yt-lockup-video ...` but there are no classes containing the prefix "yt-lockup" when I search the results from inspect element.